# Yii Count Number of rows affected

Tags: php, yii

How I can get the number of affected rows in YII , i found

```
countBySql($sql,$params=array())
```

But countBySql() requires sql query & parameters, meanwhile deleteAll() just requires only condition and parameters.

```
deleteAll(mixed $condition='', array $params=array ( ))
```

So how can i get Number of rows affected in Yii after rows are delete.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you assign it to a variable, it will give you affected count:

```
$result = deleteAll('some condition');
echo $result; // print the effected count
```

read [this](http://yiiapi.com/CActiveRecord#deleteAll-detail)

Comment: oh! thks tinyByte, i guess i didn't read the docs properly, else i would have saw that!